# What is the difference between the 2 snippets of code below

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
np.array(df[column_name].values)
```

and,

```
df[column_name].values
```

I'm aware that both of them return an array, but how do they differ?

Comment: Do they differ?

Comment: @goalie1998, yes, they should

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, `np.array` will copy the array provided to it. The actual scenarios in which it copies is in [the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

By default, it should make a new copy of the provided array, as in your case. The reason why you would want to do this is because `df.values` will provide direct access to the data stored in the dataframe. Copying the values would allow manipulations of the copy while keeping the original state of the dataframe intact.

#### Here's a quick test you can try:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((10,)) # create a random array (analogous to df.values)

b1 = a # direct assignment, no np.array()
b2 = np.array(a) # now use np.array(), should copy

print(a)

# Let's now modify the original array a, and see which variables change:
a[0] += 10

print("Modified:")
print(a)
print(b1)
print(b2)

# You'll see that b1 and a will reflect the change, but not b2,
# since b2 was a copy
```

Answer (score 1):

Its essentially the same thing

[values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is the property of a DataFrame returning a `numpy` representation

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=['BUBD01','BUBD01','BUBD16','BUBD04','BUBD05','BUBD12','BUBD21','BUBD10'],columns=['x_kod'])


>>> df['x_kod'].values
array(['BUBD01', 'BUBD01', 'BUBD16', 'BUBD04', 'BUBD05', 'BUBD12',
       'BUBD21', 'BUBD10'], dtype=object)
>>> type(df['x_kod'].values)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>>

#### Here you are again trying to convert a numpy array to numpy again , which is not required

>>> np.array(df['x_kod'].values)
array(['BUBD01', 'BUBD01', 'BUBD16', 'BUBD04', 'BUBD05', 'BUBD12',
       'BUBD21', 'BUBD10'], dtype=object)

>>> type(np.array(df['x_kod'].values))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

One should use `.values` property if you want the contents in a `numpy.ndarray`